# Regexp to match any of the substrings

Tags: regex

How can I make regular expression to match if any of the substrings is at any point of the string?

I mean if I define substrings "one" and "two" these are a match:

- One
- Two
- Blah one blah
- foo bar two baz.

So it also needs to be case insensitive. I need this in auto reply app on Android so I can only use one regular expression.

Comment: Try `(?i)\b(?:one|two)\b`. The word boundaries (`\b`) are to prevent matching `"one"` in `"toner"` or `"two"` in `"trustworthy"`, for example.

Comment: This only works if it's exact match (one) but doesn't work in other cases (blah one blah).

Comment: Did I misunderstand the question? Don't you just want to know if the string contains the word `"one"` or `"two"` (case-indifferent)? [ref](https://regex101.com/r/arEf79/1/). Move your cursor through the regex at the link for details.

Comment: You understood correctly. Looks like it works in here but not in my app. Only strings "one" and "two" trigger my responder app to reply. Probably a bug or is there some version issues on regex or other kind of incompatibility?

Comment: I can't really say without more information. Are you saying the regex I suggested responds to `"one"` but not `"One"` (i.e., case-indifference is the problem)? Keep in mind that I tested with the PCRE (PHP) regex engine. `(?i)` in the regex might not be recognized by your Android application (but not raise an error). If so there may another way to set the case-indifference flag. Can you enter `/\b(?:one|two)\b/i`?

Comment: Casing doesn't matter. It only works with one word: one/two. If there is any characters/words around the word it doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the expression:

```
/(one|two)\b/i
```

The `i` flag denotes case-insensitivity

Comment: Why the capture groups?

Comment: Because it's the simplest way to check for multiple whole words. And the logical or operator in the middle allows for either to return true

Comment: I better understand your question now. To that, I say: I wrote it poorly lol. I've updated by answer accordingly